# Printing a series based on recursion program in Python

Tags: python, recursion, design-patterns

I am trying to write a recursive program in Python to print a series. Following is my code:

```py
def pattern(n,k):
    if n > 0:
        print(n, end = ',')
        print(pattern(n-k,k), end=',')
        print(n,end = ',')
    else:
        print(n,end = ',')

pattern(12,5)
```

The output should be in the form: `12,7,2,-3,2,7,12` i.e. starting with n, and then successively minus 5 till it reaches 0 or negative number and then sums 5 until it reaches 12

But as output I am getting the following: 
`12,7,2,-3,None,2,None,7,None,12,`

Why am I getting the None? How can I remove it and print it as per the condition above?

Comment: Your function always returns `None`, which means that `print(pattern(n-k,k), end=',')` will print `None` to your console.

Comment: http://www.pythontutor.com/visualize.html#code=def%20pattern%28n,k%29%3A%0A%20%20%20%20if%20n%20%3E%200%3A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20print%28n,%20end%20%3D%20','%29%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20print%28pattern%28n-k,k%29,%20end%3D','%29%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20print%28n,end%20%3D%20','%29%0A%20%20%20%20else%3A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20print%28n,end%20%3D%20','%29%0A%0Apattern%2812,5%29&cumulative=false&curInstr=24&heapPrimitives=true&mode=display&origin=opt-frontend.js&py=3&rawInputLstJSON=%5B%5D&textReferences=false

Take a look at the visualization to understand why it's printing `None`

Answer (score 0):

Hi The problem with your code is that you are trying to print the function pattern, which return none by default in Python, Hence you should do :

```
def pattern(n,k):
    if n > 0:
        print(n, end = ',')
        pattern(n-k,k) # just simply call the function and do not print it
        print(n,end = ',')
    else:
        print(n,end = ',')
```

Comment: Thank you. I got the issue. !

Answer (score 0):

Your pattern is a decrease from outer edges to the middle.  each step in the recursion should combine the smaller substring with the value on each side (only print the final result at the end):

```
def pattern(n,k):
    if n <= 0: return str(n)
    return f"{n}, {pattern(n-k,k)}, {n}"
```

output:

```
print(pattern(16,5))

# 16, 11, 6, 1, -4, 1, 6, 11, 16
```

Ideally, you should separate computing from rendering so the function should work with numbers and you can format them as a string for printing at the end:

```
def pattern(n,k):
    return [n] if n<=0 else [n]+pattern(n-k,k)+[n]

print(pattern(n,k)) 
# [16, 11, 6, 1, -4, 1, 6, 11, 16]

# or

print(", ".join(map(str,pattern(16,5)))) 
# 16, 11, 6, 1, -4, 1, 6, 11, 16
```